# How to get invoice increment_id on order grid? (Magento 1.7)

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I'm trying to get the increment_id from the sales_flat_invoice table to appear on my orders grid.

I've managed to do that, but then it will only show orders which has been invoiced.

The sum it up, what I'm trying to do, is to create a column which contain the increment_id of the invoice (if the order has been invoiced - if not, it should be blank).

**The code is used was the following:**

In _prepareCollection() :

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
{
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass());
    $collection->getSelect()
    ->join(
        array('address' => $collection->getTable("sales/order_address")),
        'main_table.entity_id = address.parent_id AND address.address_type = "shipping"',
        array('postcode')
    );
    //$collection->join('invoice', 'main_table.entity_id = invoice.order_id', 'increment_id as invoice_id');


    $this->setCollection($collection);
    return parent::_prepareCollection();
}
```

In _prepareColumns() :

```
    $this->addColumn('invoice_id', array(
        'header' => 'Faktureret',
        'index' => 'invoice_id',
        'width' => '70px',
        'type' => 'text',
    ));
```

Thanks and have a beautiful day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do a LEFT JOIN. Use ->joinLeft. ->join references to ->joinInner

Comment: Could you please share the complete code? I have this problem too. But when I use: $collection->joinLeft('invoice', 'main_table.entity_id = invoice.order_id', 'increment_id as invoice_id'); it doesn't work.

Comment: So what's your current status? You're also getting not enough invoices?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add the invoice id in the sales order grid then you can use the following code in your prepareCollection() function as

```
$collection->getSelect()->joinLeft('sales_flat_invoice', 'main_table.entity_id = sales_flat_invoice.order_id', 'increment_id as invoice_id');
```

By using the following code you will able to get the invoice id from the current order id in sales order grid.
after this add column field as

```
$this->addColumn('invoice_id',
        array(
            'header'=> $this->__('Invoice Id'),
            'align' =>'right',
            'type=' => 'text',
            'index' => 'invoice_id',
        )
        );
```

For more follow me on 
http://www.webtechnologycodes.com

Answer (score 0):

To get invoice details from order detail. you can use

$_orders = $this->getOrders();
$_invoices = $_order->getInvoiceCollection();